# How Print the value from array in this form

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have this code,
How can print value"ID" from array,
for Function "Echo '...' ".

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 1
    )
)
```

Thank you in advance;

Comment: The first array should be mapped to a variable, such as `$arr`, the second array is available at the index of `[0]`, so `$arr[0]`, then the 'id' is available with the key `id`, so `$arr[0]['id']`

Comment: `echo $arr[0]['id']`;

Comment: yeah thank you bro , echo $pagination[0]['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: `echo $array[0]['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign that array into a variable like:

```
$array = array( 
          array( 'id' => '1' )
         );
```

And access it using:

```
echo $array[0]['id'];
```